# How can I boost the volume on my Droid's speaker?

Tags: motorola-droid, volume-control

I used to have an app for my Treo called "Volume Care" that let me boost the volume of my speaker beyond what the factory settings allowed.  Is there any app or hack that would allow me to push my Droids speaker further than Motorola wants to allow?

**Edit:** I thought I was clear before, but let me clarify.  **I am not looking for just any volume control app**, I have one, I know of many, and believe it or not I am capable of searching the market for the word "volume."  I am specifically looking for a solution that will allow me to **push the volume out of my speaker past that current manufacturer set limits.**

**Update:** I just added a bounty so I'll add a bit more clarification.  I have seen apps out there that work with HTC phones only.  This solution/app/hack must work on the Original Moto Droid rooted or not, I want a noticeable increase in the volume.

Comment: Is this a good idea? I wonder if installing something like this could actually blow out your speaker.

Comment: It most definitely could, but that's a risk I'm willing to take.

Comment: I'm sure there are music apps that can amplify the song before passing the audio to the system, but you are looking for a system-wide amplification?

Comment: Yes, system wide, but I'd be interested to see those granular solutions.

Comment: If you root your Droid and install CyanogenMod there is something called [DSP Manager](http://bel.fi/~alankila/android-dsp/) included which seems to do what you want. [The link is dead, but the off-shoot projects still exist on GitHub] -- edited by Moderator Firelord.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that Android DSP apps all do different things and you'll have to try different ones to see if they work for your particular phone and ROM.  I haven't had any luck tracking down why this is the case, or even what the apps are doing.  One time I even tried modifying a config file that by all appearances controlled volume levels, to no avail.

I have found one that works for my Note II running OctOS L, and it's called [Volume Booster](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.goodev.volume.booster&hl=en_US).  It's ad supported, and occasionally stops working, but it's great.  I boost about 25 - 30%, which is loud enough to hear music across a room at a decent level.  At that level, there are sometimes some distortions.  Also, I think it negatively impacts phone audio, but since I don't make many calls, I haven't looked into this problem.

Given the distortion, I think that this app meets your requirement to get louder than the manufacturer intended.  I presume that if I boost too much with this app, it will blow the speaker.

From the Play store:

> Simple, small, free app to boost your speaker or headphone sound
>   volume. Useful for movies, audio books and music.
>
> Use at your own risk. Playing audio at high volumes, especially for a
>   prolonged amount of time, can destroy speakers and/or damage hearing.
>   Some users HAVE reported destroyed speakers and earphones. If you hear
>   distorted audio, lower the volume (but it may be too late).
>
> By installing this application you agree that you will not hold its
>   developer responsible for any damage to hardware or hearing, and you
>   are using it at your own risk. Consider this to be experimental
>   software.
>
> Not all devices support this software. Try it at your own risk and see
>   if yours works.
>
> This app does not work on most 4.2.1-4.3 devices. It should work on
>   4.4 and higher, as well as on devices below 4.2.1.
>
> This is not for adjusting the speakerphone volume in phone calls (that
>   has its own boost, I think), but for adjusting the volume of music,
>   movies and apps.
>
> When you set the boost to zero, Volume Booster will be off. The
>   notification icon is just for ease of launching. If you don't like
>   seeing the notification icon when Volume Booster is off, just go to
>   Volume Booster's Settings and set it to appear only when Volume
>   Booster is running.

Answer (score 1):

Magisk modules are the answer to your solution, but which one depends on a trial and error method. Viper4Android & Dolby Atmos are the 2 options that come to mind.