# How to increase music playback volume?

Tags: volume-control

The volume on my headphones (even on maximum) isn't very high at all. Is there any way I can increase the volume higher than the program allows?

Comment: Which device are you asking for?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I boost the volume on my Droid's speaker?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1262/how-can-i-boost-the-volume-on-my-droids-speaker)

Comment: @Keyboardsurfer: For HTC legend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know I may not be understanding your question the way you intend it but Bryan Denny just pointed out [AndroidAudioHacks.com](http://androidaudiohacks.com/home/application) which I believe will solve your problem but not mine (because it only works on HTC phones).

via [Bryan's answer to another similar question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1776/google-nexus-one-android-2-2-listen-volume-very-low/1777#1777)

Comment: The AndroidAudioHacks.com link is a 404 (looks like the site got redesigned).  I think its now: http://androidaudiohacks.com/home/louder-volume-hack-pre-nexus

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so. But depends of the application, if it's open source you can submit a patch or ask for bug fix/new feature.