# Google Nexus One Android 2.2 -- Listen Volume very low

Tags: nexus-one, volume-control

I find that podcasts have very low volume on my nexus one, using the google listen application while using headphones.  My headphones have no volume control, and the nexus one is turned up to the max.  I don't suppose there's any way to up this more?  As it is now, I can't listen to podcasts while I'm on the bus/metro since the ambient noise drowns them out.  Maybe I can talk to the city to see if they will lower the volume on their public transit systems!

Comment: Similar question: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1766/increase-music-playback-volume

Answer (score 1):

This [website](http://androidaudiohacks.com/home/) has some audio hacks for some phones (looks like HTC phones).  Also it may not work on Android 2.1+.  You have to rooted to use this.

Comment: How does this "let you bypass normal volume levels beyond what the normal UI lets you do"?  You are the second person to recommend this but I don't see where it is indicated that it will allow you to bypass the manufacturer's volume limits. All it does is puts all the stock volume controls in one place.

Comment: @Matt strike it, I found something else that I had found before.  Only works on HTC phones tho. I think the other app that as posted was because some (or one specific) phones have a UI bug with the sound volumes?  I believe it is the Droid X, but I can't remember.