# How can I make my Samsung Galaxy Nexus volume go louder than what stock allows?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, volume-control, samsung-galaxy-nexus

I find the media volume to not be very loud on my Samsung Galaxy Nexus and would like to somehow "boost" it beyond what stock Android allows. My phone is rooted and is running Ice Cream Sandwich (Android 4.0).

Is there a way that I can "boost" my phone's volume / make it louder that works on Android 4.0?

In particular, I am wanting to do this for media playback than notification sounds, but information on either is beneficial.

Comment: Unlocked and rooted, or pure stock?  I remember for my Nexus One such a mod required kernel tweaks.

Comment: @Chahk Unlocked and rooted

Comment: See also: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1262/how-can-i-boost-the-volume-on-my-droids-speaker

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I use a program called [Volume+ Free](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.FREE.android.lvh).  Works pretty well.  The free one is capped though at +4 db.  If you want to go higher you have to get the paid version.

The [full version](http://www.androidaudiohacks.com/) can be found for free on the developer's website.

Comment: The first dialog of the app explicitly says "This application will ONLY work if your phone is running Android 2.3." Does it still work on 4.0? I'm not noticing any difference in volume after trying it myself... or if it is changing it, it is very, very minimal

Comment: Okay, I have no idea what happened but it now works when it previously didn't.

Comment: Boosts a bit on my new nexus as i am hard of hearing . Better then before on +4 . Ill hsve to buy full version to get +8 on volume+ no mod required tho bass ajustment or virtual room will make the volume drop

Comment: Seems to be working for me on my Galaxy Nexus (could be a placebo effect though, haven't done a lot of testing).

Comment: I just tried out this app on my rooted HTC Sensation. Works great, thanks for the answer.

Comment: Volume+ 1.8 has proper support for ICS, works very well on Galaxy Nexus.

Comment: I would recommend purchasing the app in the Market to support the developer (as well as get easy updates).

Comment: Works fine for me! Put it up to +10 and it is miles louder! Could do with turning it down to be honest so I would recommend this as a start. Adam

Answer (score 4):

I was searching for a way to increase the volume on my phone, before I realized the quietness was because my ear buds needed cleaning.  I used an old toothbrush and rubbing alcohol to clean mine.  Made everything much louder.

Answer (score 2):

Hey there I would like to suggest you that you should use a custom Kernel like Franco.

**Edited**:-
[this](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1367341) is the link for the franco kernel.

and this will help because it have volume gain option that will help in boosting the voice in both the phone and the headset

hope this helped

Comment: What does that do? How does it solve the problem (if it even still exists, as this question was inactive for already 1.5 years)? Please, instead of simply dropping a name, provide some context. Thank you!

Comment: I have edit the answer 
,I am newbie so .....,

thanx for the help

Comment: Thanks for the update -- yes, now it looks really helpful! And yes, I saw you're new to this site, that's why I placed the "hints to improvement" :) Glad they proved helpful. So a late welcome along!