# How can I set my volume to be beyond 15 on my samsung galaxy S?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, settings, volume-control

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I make my Samsung Galaxy Nexus volume go louder than what stock allows?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17319/how-can-i-make-my-samsung-galaxy-nexus-volume-go-louder-than-what-stock-allows)

The volume on my media music player sounds very low on my headphones. Wondering if anyone knows a way on how to increase the set volume from 15 to 30.

Answer (score 1):

There are several apps allowing you to boost your volume above the set limit -- simply [search the playstore for "volume booster"](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=volume+booster&c=apps). One examples would be [Speaker Boost](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mobi.omegacentauri.SpeakerBoost).

Without "external help" you also could try playing with your Equalizer (if there's any such pre-installed on your device -- otherwise you might get it at the playstore as well).