# Music just won't play loud enough on Samsung Galaxy S4 i9500

Tags: audio

On my Macbook Pro, iTunes lets me take advantage of my Sennheiser HD 380 headphones. I can lift the sound as loud as I like.

On my Samsung Galaxy S4 i9500, I just can't get near as loud a response from my headphones. It's very quiet.

(How can my computer's operating system give me far greater feedback than the Android operating system on my phone?)

Please advise how I can achieve the same sound quality with the Android OS.

Thank you.

Comment: What about the headphone that came with the phone is it audible enough?

Comment: Yes I would say they were.

Comment: Related, and might have suitable solutions for you: [How can I set my volume to be beyond 15 on my samsung galaxy S?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/33701/16575) / [How can I boost the music volume higher than the max limit?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/30527/16575)

Answer (score 1):

This might actually not be a problem caused by the operating system but rather by how much voltage the device can output into the headphones.
So, your Macbook is more likely to have a more powerful audio output than your S4.
The key word here is impedance. I assume the headphones you mentioned have a impedance too high for mobile devices, such as the S4.